# Unable to change instance attribute

Tags: python, pygame

I have made my own Class **Button** and I'm trying to modify `self.text_color`(in ***mybutton.py*** under [#Rectangle (**comment**)] ) from *main.py*
with this command `button1.text_color = (25,25,25)` but I can't see any change. All other properties are modifying except this one. You copy and run the code to check the problem.

***main.py***

```
import pygame
import sys
from mybutton import Button
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Gui Menu')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

button1 = Button('Click me', (255,255,255), (255,0,0), 200, 40, ((500-200)//2, 200))
button2 = Button('Click me', (2,25,255), (255,25,255), 200, 40, ((500-200)//2, 100))
button1.text_color = (25,25,25)
button1.hov_bg_color = (25,255,25)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    a = button1.draw(screen)
    b = button2.draw(screen)
    
    print(button1.text_color)
    
    if a != None:
        print(a)
    elif b != None:
        print(b)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

***mybutton.py***

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


class Button:
    unq_number = 0

    def __init__(self, text, bg_color, hov_bg_color, width, height, pos):
        self.pressed = False

        # unique number for each button
        Button.unq_number += 1
        self.unq_number = Button.unq_number

        # Rectangle
        self.org_width = width
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
        self.border_radius = 12
        self.org_bg_color = bg_color
        self.bg_color = self.org_bg_color
        self.hov_bg_color = hov_bg_color
        self.trans_speed = 4
        self.trans_len = 30
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        self.text_color = (0, 0, 0)

        # text
        self.text_surf = self.font.render(text, True, self.text_color)
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.bg_color, self.rect,
                         border_radius=self.border_radius)
        surface.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        return self.check_click()

    def check_click(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.bg_color = self.hov_bg_color
            if self.rect.width < (self.org_width + self.trans_len):
                self.rect.width += self.trans_speed
                self.rect.x -= self.trans_speed/2

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.pressed = True
            else:
                if self.pressed == True:
                    self.pressed = False
                    return self.unq_number
        else:
            if self.rect.width > self.org_width:
                self.rect.width -= self.trans_speed
                self.rect.x += self.trans_speed/2
            self.bg_color = self.org_bg_color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the text doesn't magically change when the `text_color` attribute is changed. The `text_color` is not tied to the surface rendered by the text, you must re-render the text with the new color if you change the color.

Add a method that changes the color attribute and renders the text with the new color:

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, text, bg_color, hov_bg_color, width, height, pos):
        # [...]

        self.text = text

    def set_text_color(self, color)
        self.text_color = color
        self.text_surf = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.text_color)
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
```

Call this method instead of changing the attribute:

```py
button1.set_text_color((25,25,25))
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to change `self.text_surf` as well when you set the `self.color`

you probably need to make a methode `def set_text_color()` that change self.text_surf text's color